# View vertex color in edit mode instead of material color?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, vertex-colors

I am using vertex color to create the colorID map for Substance Painter. I canot use materials for this, because I use materials to define Substance Painter's textures sets (there is no other way for the latter as far as I know). Is there any way I can view the vertex color in the viewport, when I am editing the model in the 'Edit mode' instead of the colors of the materials?

Comment: It should be possible to select Attribute node with mentioned vertex colors, press Ctrl+Left click to preview selected node and then enter Material mode in 3d viewport (essentially previewing material but when it's set to show vertex colors).

Comment: Could you show a guide/explain in details how to do it? I am new to blender and it is really hard to even try to follow you.

Comment: [A quick gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xIWY.gif) of previewing vertex colors in Edit mode with material shading mode

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.8+, select *Solid* [viewport shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html) and click the arrow button to bring up the viewport shading menu. Set [*Color*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workbench/color.html) to *Vertex*. Setting [*Lighting*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workbench/lighting.html) to *Flat* may also be helpful.

[image]